# Add class to slot scope

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm creating a table component, and I want to give the ability to my users to add their custom `<td>` thanks to a slot.
So I have:

```
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="(item, key) in items">
    <slot :item=item">
      <td v-for="(header, headerKey) in variableHeaders"
        :class="{
            veryImportantClass: condition > 5,
        }">
        {{item.text}}
      </td>
    </slot>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

And I use this slot thanks to this code:

```
<my-component
  :headers="headers"
  :items="items">
  <template slot-scope="prop">
    <td :class="{ aClassAddedByAUser: true }" v-for="(header, headerKey) in headers" ...>
      {{ prop.item.text }} with some text
    </td>
  </template>
</my-component>
```

The issue is, the `veryImportantClass` class is mandatory for my component, but I would like to avoid to ask my users to input it in their created `slot` (to decrease complexity)

Is there a way to simply add this class to all `<td>` given by my users thanks to this scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `mounted()` life-cycle hook to add the class using normal JavaScript functions. Here's how you could unconditionally add it to all cells. If you only need to add it to some cells, adjust accordingly.

```
mounted() {
    // wait a tick to ensure all child components have rendered
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.$el.querySelectorAll("td")
            .forEach(td => {
                td.classList.add("veryImportantClass");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You might need to do something similar on `updated()` if the slot content is going to change.

Note: This does assume that the parent inserts `<td>` elements in the slot, which is not guaranteed. But since that would result in invalid HTML, you may be okay living with that assumption

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! So we are not using reactivity here. Is it clean?

Comment: Vue 2.6 changes how reactivity is handled for slots, so you might want to play it safe and add explicit watchers for properties that may result in updated content.